# Determine best model for variable selection process

Tags: feature-selection

When we do variable selection, theoretically we fit a model for each selected subset of variables. We can then compare all models and select the best.

There are various statistic to help selecting best model, such as Bayesian information criterion, adjusted R2.

My question is that why can't we just use the RSE or R2 that are statistics used for model accuracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because those values almost always go up with more variables -- they can't go down, and, in practical terms, they can't stay constant. They may go up by very small amounts. So they would favor huge models. E.g.

```
set.seed(1234)

x1 <-  rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)

y <- 3*x1 + rnorm(100, 0, 5) #Note that there is no x2 term

m1 <- lm(y~x1)
summary(m1) #RSE = 4.809 R^2 = 0.3363
m2 <- lm(y~ x1 + x2)
summary(m2) #RSE = 4.812 R^2 = 0.3423
```

EDIT: So, why is that a problem? Because the result can be nonsense. Let's say that, for some reason, you are doing completely exploratory research. You have no idea if there any relationships. And, in one case, you have a data set where there are no relationships in the population except those due to chance. You test a sample. You will build a big model, with lots of variables, if you go just by R^2 or RSE. This model won't work on other samples, the parameter estimates won't tell you anything, etc. If your data set has 10 independent variables, you will get a model with all 10.

One view of statistics is that it helps you distinguish signal from noise. Maximizing R^2 or RSE does not do this. (Of course, this is not the *only* of statistics and it does other things as well, but signal from noise is a big one).

When building a model (as with regression models), sometimes you are after prediction; other times interpretation; often both. But maximizing R^2 or RSE does neither.

Just try it with a train and test data set and see what happens.

Comment: Correct on all points, but not apparently relevant: why would "favor huge models" be a problem? ;-)

Comment: OK, I'll add more about that.